# How to color date range in SAPUI5 date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

Is there a way to change the color of the range in the date picker, so from the *date from* to *date to* like on the image? 14. - 23.

[image]

Comment: It can be changed with some 'inline' styling, or with a custom theme. However you should be careful with the first option - don't override globally UI5 classes, prefix your own rule, asses the right place to put this rule.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to select a date range, you should use the `DateRangeSelector`. It visibly marks the selected date range. Documentation  and Samples: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.DateRangeSelection/sample/sap.m.sample.DateRangeSelection